# Calculating $H_n(\mathbb{Z}, \mathbb{Z})$ group homology.

Tags: homology-cohomology, homological-algebra, group-cohomology

I've been looking for some concrete examples of group homology calculations and have been struggling to find any so I thought I'd work through one myself that should be simple: $H_n(\mathbb{Z}, \mathbb{Z})$, but need some help making the last step.

I made a free $\mathbb{Z}[\mathbb{Z}]$-resolution of $\mathbb{Z}$:
$$ \cdots\rightarrow\mathbb{Z}[\mathbb{Z}]\rightarrow\mathbb{Z}[\mathbb{Z}]\rightarrow\mathbb{Z}[\mathbb{Z}]\xrightarrow{\partial_0}\mathbb{Z}\rightarrow0 $$
With:
$$ \partial_0:\mathbb{Z}[\mathbb{Z}]\rightarrow\mathbb{Z} $$ 
$$(a_0,a_1,\dots) \mapsto a_0$$
and the other maps created to fit in with exactness and $\ker{\partial_0}$. I then tensor over $\mathbb{Z}[\mathbb{Z}]$ with $\mathbb{Z}$:
$$ \cdots\rightarrow\mathbb{Z}[\mathbb{Z}]\otimes_{\mathbb{Z}[\mathbb{Z}]}\mathbb{Z}\rightarrow\mathbb{Z}[\mathbb{Z}]\otimes_{\mathbb{Z}[\mathbb{Z}]}\mathbb{Z}\rightarrow\mathbb{Z}[\mathbb{Z}]\otimes_{\mathbb{Z}[\mathbb{Z}]}\mathbb{Z}\rightarrow\mathbb{Z}\otimes_{\mathbb{Z}[\mathbb{Z}]}\mathbb{Z}$$
Which I know becomes:
$$\cdots \rightarrow \mathbb{Z} \rightarrow \mathbb{Z} \rightarrow \mathbb{Z}\rightarrow\mathbb{Z}\otimes_{\mathbb{Z}[\mathbb{Z}]}\mathbb{Z}$$
And it is at this point I know I need the homology of this sequences and that is where I am getting stuck. Can anyone point me in the right direction? and does anyone have any group homology calculation examples they know of online?

Comment: Maybe you want to compute group homology directly, but one way to do it (at least in this case) is to use the fact that the group homology of $G$ is the singular homology of a $K(G, 1)$. As $K(\mathbb{Z}, 1) = S^1$, the homology is easy to compute.

Comment: Thank you, thats good to know, so it should be $\mathbb{Z}$ in $n=0,1$ I see. But yeah I do need to know how to do it in full because I need to use the Lyndon–Hochschild-Serre spectral sequence for a group homology project and so should understand group homology from scratch properly.

Comment: I might be misunderstanding your notation, but the map $\partial_0$ you wrote down doesn't seem to be a map of $\mathbb{Z}[\mathbb{Z}]$-modules.  Also, how did you know that there is a free resolution that is degreewise of rank $1$ without knowing the other differentials?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a short free resolution of $\mathbb{Z}$ as a trivial $\mathbb{Z}[\mathbb{Z}]$-module: $$0 \to \mathbb{Z}[\mathbb{Z}] \xrightarrow{\partial} \mathbb{Z}[\mathbb{Z}] \xrightarrow{\epsilon} \mathbb{Z} \to 0.$$

The map $\epsilon: \mathbb{Z}[\mathbb{Z}] \to \mathbb{Z}$ is the usual augmentation, given by $[n] \mapsto 1$.  The map $\partial: \mathbb{Z}[\mathbb{Z}] \to \mathbb{Z}[\mathbb{Z}]$ is the map $[n] \mapsto [n] - [n-1]$.  You should verify that this complex is exact.  Tensoring this resolution down with $\mathbb{Z}$, we get the complex $$0 \to \mathbb{Z} \xrightarrow{\bar{\partial}} \mathbb{Z} \to 0.$$  The map $\bar{\partial}$ is the zero map, so the homology of this chain complex is $\mathbb{Z}$ in degrees $0, 1$, and is trivial in other degrees.  Hence $$H_n(\mathbb{Z}, \mathbb{Z}) \cong \begin{cases} \mathbb{Z}, & n = 0, 1 \\ 0, & \text{else}. \end{cases}$$  This agrees with the answer given in Michael's comment.

Comment: Just to be clear, this not only agrees with the final answer in the comment of @MichaelAlbanese, it also agrees with the method, in the following sense. Let $\mathbb{R} \mapsto S^1$ be the universal covering map $t \mapsto e^{2\pi i t}$. If you take the $\mathbb{Z}$-invariant CW complex of the universal covering space $\mathbb{R}$, with vertex set $\mathbb{Z} \subset \mathbb{R}$, then the $\mathbb{Z}[\mathbb{Z}]$ chain complex structure induced from that $\mathbb{Z}$-CW complex is isomorphic to the $\mathbb{Z}[\mathbb{Z}]$ module written down in this answer.

Comment: Thanks very much, that was really useful to see explicitly done!